# Selling Products world wide from Australia + Accepting Multiple Currency

Tags: expresso-store, cartthrob, shipping, shopping-cart, currency

I have used Expresso Store for all my carts to date, and have no experience in any other EE cart solutions, nor have I done a multi currency site before.

I can see in Expresso's documentation that they potentially have Multiple Currency in development.

My question is:

Has anyone out there delivered a shopping cart using Expression Engine which handled Multiple Currencies well along with shipping options/calculator for Australia?

Answer (score 1):

Store currently only supports charging cards in a single currency per site which you set in the Store > Settings > General tab in the CP. Lets say that you have it set to USD and your customer is from England and therefor is paying with British Pounds. The payment gateway will convert the currency so that you collect the correct amount in USD.